# Calling stored procedures slower than simple prepared statements

Tags: java, sql, oracle, query-optimization

An issue is affecting all queries made to our database where the query takes far longer when run by calling a stored procedure.

It seems like usually this would be a parameter-sniffing issue, but I'm still seeing this problem for dummy queries I've been using to test performance that don't use parameters at all. For example, executing

```
UPDATE TestTable
SET field = 'test'
WHERE id = 1;
```

from a prepared statement 10000 times takes .6 seconds, while calling

```
PROCEDURE plsqlTest(...)
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE TestTable
  SET field = 'test'
  WHERE id = 1;
END plsqlTest;
```

the same amount takes over 20 seconds. Is there something else that could cause such a huge disparity?

Comment: I suspect the overhead is calling the stored procedure 10,000 times.  In addition, the timing might depend on how transactions are being handled between the two timing comparisons.

Comment: The basic query is still being run from a prepared statement, so would there be much difference in overhead? If anything I'd expect the stored procedure to perform better (I'll clarify the original question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very well known problem. When you run a SQL statement, Oracle runs it in the SQL engine. When you run a PL/SQL procedure that executes a SQL statement, there is a *context switch* between the PL/SQL and SQL engines. This isn't very large, but when done many times over will slow down performance significantly.

Stephen Feuerstein writes about this a lot: https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/solving-the-row-by-row-problem